# Compiling a .java file on linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to run a .java file, but when I compile the file I get this error

```
Command 'javac' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install default-jdk            
apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless
apt install ecj                    
apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

But I have java jdk installed and when I check i get this message

```
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I need this for a course I am taking and when I try installing one of the listed files, I get this.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: default-jdk-headless (= 2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-11-jdk but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-74-generic but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Maybe you only have the runtime installed without the JDK.

Comment: I think @JanezKuhar is right. The project's name is "OpenJDK" but it says you have the "OpenJDK Runtime Environment" on your machine.

Comment: How do I install whatever else I need?

Comment: I'd start with: `apt install default-jdk`,
`apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless`,
`apt install ecj`, or 
`apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless`

Comment: `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless` (assuming you want java 11). Personally, I would suggest you try [sdkman!](https://sdkman.io/)

Comment: This seems more like a debian/linux question than a programming one.

Comment: Do you know where I should ask?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have JRE installed. You'll need to install JDK as well to get javac (the Java compiler). Just use one of the apt commands suggested.

Comment: How do I comment code? I go over the character limit.

Comment: Just add it to the question.

Can you try running "sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk"?

Comment: i get a similar message to the one in my question (the last code)

Comment: The error message provides the solution. Run apt install with "--fix_broken".

Answer (score 0):

If you have jdk installed then seems you need to update your path variable. This should fix the issue.

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I tried
```
export PATH=/home/faiq/Desktop/jre1.8.0_241/bin:$PATH
```
but the same thing happened

Comment: because you have a JRE and not JDK... :)

Comment: I don't have that much experience with linux. How do i find the path to the jdk file?

Comment: Assuming you want to install JDK 8, download it from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and then follow instructions from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFJJEFG)